# Oauth Cloning on github not working (fatal: Authentication failed)

Tags: git, oauth, github, cloning

I am trying to test my app in github. I had a friend of mine authorize my app to access private and public repos and that all went fine. Despite this for some reason i can't seem to clone his repos using the Oauth Token i got back after he authorized with my app.

I cloned by using the instruction outlined in this link: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth

The out come in terminal looks like:

```
Cloning into 'repoName...
fatal: Authentication failed
```

What is the actual cause of this error? I made sure my app was properly authorized. Could it have something to do with my ssh key on my computer? It was my understanding that using the token i would not need an ssh key to clone.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. I just tried it and it worked for me. Here's what I did:

1. create new token using [Authorizations API](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization). Note that you have to specify that the token should be for (at least) the `repo` [scope](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).
2. git clone a private repo using the HTTP URL of the repo (not the git or ssh URL)
3. enter the token I received as the username and nothing (blank) as the password.

If I had to guess what the problem is in your scenarion, I would say it is one of these two things (or both):

1. the token you created does not contain the `repo` scope which is necessary for cloning
2. the URL you are using for cloning is not an HTTP URL, rather a GIT or SSH URL. Make sure you are using the HTTP URL of the repo you are cloning.