# Cloning private github repos without deploy keys?

Tags: git, github, cloning

I am trying to build an application that can clone a person's private repo (with permission), and run analysis on it, similar to what codeclimate does. I would like to do this without using deploy keys or messing with ssh. I notice codeclimate uses the Oauth for github and it takes only one click, but I tested that on my app and I run into the problem I outline in this question : [Oauth Cloning on github not working (fatal: Authentication failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817709/oauth-cloning-on-github-not-working-fatal-authentication-failed)

So what method can I use to clone a private git repo when granted permission and without the user creating deploy keys using my github application?

Answer (score 1):

1. define your app in github : https://github.com/settings/applications
2. add a deploy (public) key :
   http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/keys/#create
3. tweak your ssh settings to use this associated private key
   [Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)
4. git clone with specific uri

Answer (score 0):

start by taking a look at the github api:

http://developer.github.com/v3

once authenticated you can view a users repos: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

once a repo is selected you can execute "git" calls from the api as well: http://developer.github.com/v3/git/

you can read commits, blobs, trees, branches, tags, refs... pretty much everything.

Comment: I noticed that yea, but iam trying to clone the whole repo, not just read the stats